# connect two raspberry pi call python function

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I have two raspberry pi's connected to a hub
One is the server and one is the client. what i want to do is run 2 python scripts on both raspberry pi's

Then call function on each raspberry so the server needs to call functions in the script that is running on the client and vice versa

But how can i do that because i dont really understand socket communication

I had a bit of code that worked but i needed the IP of both raspberry's all the time.

So hope someone can help so i can call functions on other raspberry pi's

Comment: They get their IP-addresses via DHCP from the router?

Comment: @joop yes they get their ip adress from the router.

Comment: Now they could start guessing the IP address for the other side. Probably 192.168.0.{100,101,102,103}. And: it is impossible to "call functions" on another machine. It *is* possible to send messages, which *could* cause the other side to "call functions".

Comment: I did this type of thing 3 years ago , can't explain exact but , you can try one hack , store python file (which you want to excute on raspberry ) in raspberry desktop or anywhere and then take ssh of both raspberry pi on your mac or linux  , after write a automation scipt (if you are using mac use automator) that login in both raspberry ssh and execute that desktop script on raspberry desktop via your terminal of linux or mac.

Comment: Can you reserve IP addresses for these devices or does the DHCP need to dish them out?